# Empty abstract function cannot contain body

Tags: abstract-class, php

I'm trying to build an abstract class (StatusService) which along with some basic logic defines methods that *need* to be present in extended classes, but am running into this error that I can't explain:

> Fatal error: Abstract function StatusService::upd() cannot contain body in /path/to/lib/services/service.class.php on line 62

Snippet of my base class:

```
abstract class StatusService {
    /** ... */

    /**
     * @return boolean
     * @abstract
     */
    abstract public function upd(){}
}
```

Now I can  be completely wrong (haven't written much abstract classes yet), but it doesn't look like it has a body to me..? I would appreciate any pointers to help figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My extended class (just one right now) does define the upd() function and returns a value, but it's still dumping that error on me. In case it matters, this is PHP 5.4.4 running on MAMP Pro.

Comment: A look in the manual should make the mistake clear at glance: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Comment: If you don't know what you're looking for and have been staring at it for a while, two braces can be hard to miss ;) that said, it's still a stupid error and some more RTFMing definitely could've clarified it. Thanks for sharing the link.

Comment: Sure, that's just additionally to the answer which somewhat missed to point to the manual as well ;)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
abstract public function upd(){}
```

should be

```
abstract public function upd();
```

Note that braces.. forms the body of a method.

Comment: ... geeee, that's a few hours I wont get back! Thanks so much for this insanely fast answer (can't even mark this as answer yet!), that got me all sorted.

Comment: @MarkHamstra It happens, but you learn something at the end of it all. Thanks and np. Good luck :)

Comment: True story. This is one mistake I wont make again! :)

Answer (score 8):

Just use

```
abstract public function upd();
```

without the braces

Comment: Thanks! Lews beat you by 10 seconds, but of course this answer is also correct.